# ¿Cómo editar una variable especifica dentro de un struct (c)?

Tags: c, csv, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Soy nuevo en c y estoy intentado de realizar un programa para una biblioteca que consiste en guardar una data.csv en un struct para poder trabajar con ella con distintas funciones, como buscar un libro y ver su información: ubicación, autor, año.

También quiero que el programa deje editar información del libro, donde el usuario coloca el nombre del libro que desee editar y lo que desee editar.

```
#include "header.h"

void main(libros biblioteca[], int numb_rows)
{
    char book[200];
    char edit[200];
    int opcion3, a, found;

    p("Ingresa el nombre del libro que deseas editar: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", book);
    for (int i = 0; i < numb_rows; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(book, biblioteca[i].titulo) == 0)
        {
            p("No se encuentra el libro. \n");
            found = 1; 
            a = i;
        }
        else
        {
            p("No se encuentra el libro. \n");
        }
    }

        if (found == 1)
        {

            p("Que informacion desea editar\n\n");
            p("[1]     Autor. \n");
            p("[2]     Titulo. \n");
            p("[3]     Anio. \n");
            p("Seleccione una opcion: ");
            s("%d", &opcion3);
            p("/n");

            switch (opcion3)
            {

                case 1:
                {
                    p("Ingrese el autor.\n");
                    scanf("%c", edit);
                    strcpy(biblioteca[a].autor, edit);
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    p("Ingrese titulo.\n");
                    scanf("%c", edit);
                    strcpy(biblioteca[a].titulo, edit);
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    p("Ingrese anio. \n");
                    scanf("%c", edit);
                    strcpy(biblioteca[a].anio, edit);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

En el `header.h` se debería encontrar el struct y las otras funciones del programa, el código me tira el error de `Segmentation fault`. Que estaré haciendo mal?

Pd: Libros es el struct principal y Biblioteca es donde se guardan los datos después de haber leído el csv.

Comment: Esta linea: `scanf("%c", edit);` está mal... `edit` es un array de caracteres, deberías de usar el especificador `%s` y de paso, le agregas el tamaño del buffer: `%199s`.

Answer (score 0):

Le hice unos cambios a tu codigo, a la variable found le faltaba iniciar en cero de manera que si no se encuentra el libro, este valor indica que no ha sido encontrado, en caso contrario (con valor 1) indica que si fue encontrado, el otro error que tenia era que tratabas de ingresar un string usando un especificador para caractrer `scanf("%c", edit);` asi que despues de la correccion quedo asi `scanf("%s", edit);` con estos cambios el codigo deberia funcionar.

```
#include "header.h"

void main(libros biblioteca[], int numb_rows){
    char book[200];
    char edit[200];
    int opcion3, a, found = 0;
    
    p("Ingresa el nombre del libro que deseas editar: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", book);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numb_rows; i++){
        if(strcmp(book, biblioteca[i].titulo) == 0){
            found = 1; 
            a = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(found == 1){
        p("Que informacion desea editar\n\n");
        p("[1]     Autor. \n");
        p("[2]     Titulo. \n");
        p("[3]     Anio. \n");
        p("Seleccione una opcion: ");
        s("%d", &opcion3);
        p("/n");
        
        switch(opcion3){
            case 1:
                p("Ingrese el autor.\n");
                scanf("%s", edit);
                strcpy(biblioteca[a].autor, edit);
                break;
            case 2:
                p("Ingrese titulo.\n");
                scanf("%s", edit);
                strcpy(biblioteca[a].titulo, edit);
                break;
            case 3:
                p("Ingrese anio.\n");
                scanf("%s", edit);
                strcpy(biblioteca[a].anio, edit);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcion invalida.\n");
                break;
        }
    }else{
        p("No se encuentra el libro.\n");
    }
}
```